# transition_post_status not working via Quick Edit

Tags: wp-admin, user-meta, post-status

I am trying to use *transition_post_status* with custom post statuses to update user meta each time a post status is updated. The following *works* when editing the post status in **Edit Post Screen**, but *does not* work when changing post status in **Quick Edit** in the admin view, which makes it difficult for the admin to change post statuses so that the change reflects in the user meta.

Is there something I might have missed?

```
function update_hit_rate( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
if ( $new_status != $old_status ) {
    global $post;

    $user_id = $post->post_author;

    $args = array(
    'author' => $user_id,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'betting_tip',
    'post_status' => array('hit','miss')
    );

    $posts = get_posts( $args );

    $hits = $misses = array();

    if ( ! empty( $posts ) ) :;
        foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
            switch ( $post->post_status ) {
                case 'hit':
                    $hits[] = $post;
                    break;
                case 'miss':
                    $misses[] = $post;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    endif;

    $hits = count($hits);
    $misses = count($misses);
    $hit_rate = round($hits / ($hits + $misses) * 100);

    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'hit_rate', $hit_rate);
  }
}
add_action( 'transition_post_status',  'update_hit_rate', 10, 3 );
```

EDIT: I am using the plugin *Extended Post Status* to add custom post statuses and status change options for the admin view. I also tried it with fully custom code, but the result is the same. User meta is updated from Edit Post screen, but from the Quick Edit menu it does nothing, even if the post status is changed.

Comment: I don't have an issue with  `transition_post_status` firing on the default `post`. The 2 types are different and `$post` is populated as expected. I suspect something elsewhere is causing this issue. Possibly the custom post status?

Comment: Is that `'post_status' => 'hit','miss'` just a typo in the question? Because that should be `'post_status' => array( 'hit', 'miss' )` ..

Comment: Yes, it's a typo. I have a broader query on the site and cleaned it up a little for the example. Thanks for pointing out! :)

Comment: Try commenting out or removing the `global $post;` in your code. If the same issue persists, try deactivating the Extended Post Status plugin.

Comment: Perfect. Removing `global $post;` solved the issue. Thank you!